# making row vectors from csv file using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Pandas to read a csv file and the file has the following data:

```
   t (s)     rx (km)    ry (km)  ...   vy (km/s)   vz (km/s)  Unnamed: 7
0     0.00     1249.93    6297.17  ...      0.5774      3.1688            
1    10.17     1176.84    6302.64  ...      0.4968      3.1855            
2    20.34     1102.64    6307.28  ...      0.4150      3.2015            
3    30.51     1027.37    6311.08  ...      0.3321      3.2168            
4    40.68      951.01    6314.03  ...      0.2481      3.2312            
5    50.85      873.60    6316.12  ...      0.1630      3.2450            
6    61.02      795.12    6317.34  ...      0.0769      3.2580            
7    71.19      715.60    6317.68  ...     -0.0103      3.2702            
8    81.36      635.03    6317.12  ...     -0.0985      3.2816
```

there are many columns so some are hidden.. basically, I want to make a vector for r = [rx,ry,rz] from each row, and v = [vx,vy,vz] from each row. Namely,i need as many rows as there are for the number of vector r, and as many rows as there are for the number of vector v(there are 60 rows so I want 60 separate vectors of r and v, with each having 3 row entries). How should I do this?
I tried using np.array in the following way:

```
rx = np.array([df['   rx (km)'].values])
ry = np.array([df['  ry (km)'].values])
rz = np.array([df['  rz (km)'].values])
r_vec =np.array([rx,ry,rz])
```

but what I get is a big chunk of all values grouped together so it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could help you:

```
df['R_vec'] = df[['rx', 'ry', 'rz']].values.tolist()
df['V_vec'] = df[['vx', 'vy', 'vz']].values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

The straight forward way of extracting a 60 x 3 array of r vectors is

```
r_arr = df[['   rx (km)', '  ry (km)', '  rz (km)']].to_numpy()
```

P.S. Those column names don't look convenient. You might be able to fix them by using the `sep` argument of `read_csv`.

Comment: Hi,
How should I use the sep argument? I've only used delimiter before and this csv looks pretty messy, I don't know how to make the column names convenient

Comment: delimiter is an alias for sep, so they're equivalent. I would just check if it's delimited with tabs or a fix number of spaces